# Likelihood with random censoring

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, inference, likelihood, censoring

Suppose to observe a random sample from a r.v. $Y_i=\min(T_i,C_i)$ where $T$ and $C$ are iid absolutely continuous distribution.

I would like to inference about a parameter of $T$ (for example, $\lambda$ in a exponential distribution). Therefore I calculate the pdf of $Y$:

$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y) = P(\min(T,C) \le y) = 1-(1-F_T(y))(1-F_C(y)) $ that implies

\begin{align}f_Y(y) &= \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = f_C(y)+f_T(y)-f_T(y)F_C(y)-F_T(y)f_C(y)\\
&= f_C(y)(1-F_T(y)) + f_T(y)(1-F_C(y)).
\end{align}

Then $L(\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^nf_Y(y_i)$.

Does my approach really answer the inferential question about a parameter of a distribution with random censoring?
I can see that usually the likelihood is calculated as:

$$L(\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^nf_C(y_i)^{\delta_i}(1-F_T(y_i))^{1-\delta_i}\prod_{i=1}^nf_T(y_i)^{1-\delta_i}(1-F_C(y_i))^{\delta_i}$$

where $\delta=1$  if the observation is censored and $\delta=0$ if not.

Comment: Yes, the likelihood is correct if the sample is i.i.d.

Comment: I can't understand the difference between my solution and the approach used for example here : https://web.stanford.edu/~lutian/coursepdf/unit2.pdf ( section 2.1) .

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: There are two likelihoods presented in the question: one observed and one completed with the censoring indicators (which are not _observed_). The second one is useful for resolutions like the EM algorithm.

Comment: So the first one is the likelihood for a random sample when we do not know if the observed value was censored or not? But I would say that if we assume the censoring mechanism is random, we cannot say if the observed value is censored or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75693/discussion-between-momomi-and-xian).